# eclipse doesn't run on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have tried to install two differens versions of Eclipse on windows 10 without any succes,the versions which I tried to install were eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64 and eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_6,in the first time whenever I was trying to run the application it was giving the error message that indicated the problem was the java version I then installed the required java version but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem as now it doesn't show the error message nor does it run!!

Comment: Have you tried running it as administrator?

Comment: If you go to Control Panel/Programs/Java/"Java" tab click _view_ button and make sure that the version you want is enabled. Also make sure the system one is marked properly as well.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have tried to do what you said but the problem still persist!!

Comment: @Havenard I have tried also to run as an administrator without succes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Eclipse dir

Edit eclipse.ini

Edit or add -vm option:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe
```

Of course, you should write reference to your javaw.exe file.

Set JAVA_HOME in eclipse-windows-preferences-java to the correct sdk folder

After that, your new java will not fit java in workspace. Create a new workspace, restart Eclipse and import your projects there. You can work.

Comment: after adding -vm it worked, but I have already JAVA_HOME pointing to same java sdk

Answer (score 0):

You need to update jdk in your system if it is not latest version. Open java configuration from start and check if there is any latest update. (It will pop up a window asking to uninstall older versions. Click Next and proceed)

After updating set JAVA_HOME, Path environmental variables. Restart the system.

It should work now!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, this problem can be solved by tweaking the values in `eclipse.ini` file located inside the Eclipse directory.

Just head over to the `eclipse.ini` file, open it and make the following changes. Be sure to attempt launching the `eclipse.exe` after each of the changes, as one or more may correct the error. 

1. point the `-vm` to the `javaw.exe` in your JDK intallation as below.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe
```

2.Check if the jdk version specified in the `eclipse.ini` file is the correct jdk that is installed in your machine. To check this, head over to the command prompt and type

```
java -version
```

After checking your jdk version, ensure that it properly updated in the `eclipse.ini` file. if your are running jdk 1.8.+, use the line below, if it's jdk 1.7.+ or below, chanage the `1.8` in the line below to the appriate version.

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

3. Find the line `-Xmx256m` (or  `-Xmx1024m`). Now change the default value `256m` (or `1024m`) to `512m` as below .

   `-Xmx512m`

Answer (score 0):

Some computers do not have a JDK installed, which is needed to run Eclipse. You need to install a JDK in order for Eclipse to work.

The Oracle website has downloads for JDKs. Below, I've linked the newest one (as of typing) that should redirect automatically to any newer versions.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html